# C# - Missing definition of object of class - how to write?

Tags: c#, object, definition, overloading

this is part of my source code:

```
var result = DiceWebAPI.PlaceAutomatedBets(
                Session, baseBet, guessLow, guessHigh,
                betCount > Session.MaxBetBatchSize ? Session.MaxBetBatchSize : betCount,
                resetOnWin, resetOnLoss,
                increaseOnWin, increaseOnLoss,
                maxBet, resetOnMaxLoss, stopOnMaxLoss, stopMaxBalance);
```

the viusal c# studio 2010 says:

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'PlaceAutomatedBets' takes 13 arguments  D:\Downloads\SampleBot_NET_3_5\SampleBot_NET_Source\Dice.Sample.Bot.3_5\Main.cs 359 30  DiceSampleBot35
```

I discovered that all arguments of method have definition except the Session one. Can anybody tell me how to write and where to place the definition?

maybe that would help:

in the other file

```
readonly SessionInfo Session;
```

and in another one

```
namespace Dice.Client.Web
{
public sealed class SessionInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string AccountCookie { get; }
    public long AccountId { get; }
    public decimal Balance { get; }
    public long BetCount { get; }
    public decimal BetPayIn { get; }
    public decimal BetPayOut { get; }
    public long BetWinCount { get; }
    public long ClientSeed { get; }
    public string DepositAddress { get; }
    public string Email { get; }
    public string EmergencyAddress { get; }
    public int MaxBetBatchSize { get; }
    public string SessionCookie { get; }
    public string Username { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
}
```

UPDATE:

PlaceAutomatedBets.. definition

```
public static PlaceAutomatedBetsResponse PlaceAutomatedBets(SessionInfo session, AutomatedBetsSettings settings);
```

Comment: if you want change constructor you need source code of DiceWebAPI.

Comment: Can you post the signature to where PlaceAutomatedBets is defined on DiceWebAPI?

Comment: @RobLang 

    public static PlaceAutomatedBetsResponse PlaceAutomatedBets(SessionInfo session, AutomatedBetsSettings settings);

in part of

 namespace Dice.Client.Web
{
    public static class DiceWebAPI
    {
(...)

}
}

Comment: Can you add that into the question. Can you also post the contents of `AutomatedBetsSettings`? It looks like you're putting all the settings in manually rather than building a `AutomatedBetsSettings` object first and passing that in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to PlaceAutomatedBets method, and, you will find that your PlaceAutomatedBets only takes 12 arguments, you will need to add the one who is missing.

Comment: Oh, I missunderstood the question. So sorry user3327653 ;)

Comment: n/p ;) have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

you are passing extra arguments. Exception is self explanatory.  and there is no need to re-define `HttpContext.Session Property` it's already there in `System.Web` if you haven't included this just put this line on top of your class `Using System.Web;`

Comment: huh? where exactly? i don't understand otherwise it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling a method that has a signature of two parameters:

```
public static PlaceAutomatedBetsResponse PlaceAutomatedBets(
             SessionInfo session,     
             AutomatedBetsSettings settings);
```

However, you are calling it with 12:

```
var result = DiceWebAPI.PlaceAutomatedBets(
            Session, baseBet, guessLow, guessHigh,
            betCount > Session.MaxBetBatchSize ? Session.MaxBetBatchSize : betCount,
            resetOnWin, resetOnLoss,
            increaseOnWin, increaseOnLoss,
            maxBet, resetOnMaxLoss, stopOnMaxLoss, stopMaxBalance);
```

C# cannot take your 12 parameters and automatically form them into an object. Instead, you have to build an `AutomatedBetsSettings` object and pass that in with `Session`. That's pretty standard in software design, where you want to reduce the number of parameters. The object with all the detail in is often called a context.

For example, you need to do something like:

```
// I am guessing the content of AutomatedBetsSettings here, you will need
// to check the actual property values.
var betSettingsContext = new AutomatedBetsSettings() {
            BaseBet = baseBet, 
            GuessLow = guessLow, 
            GuessHigh = guessHigh,
            BestCount = betCount > Session.MaxBetBatchSize ? Session.MaxBetBatchSize : betCount,
            ResetOnWin = resetOnWin, 
            ResetOnLoss = resetOnLoss,
            IncreaseOnWin = increaseOnWin, 
            IncreaseOnLoss = increaseOnLoss,
            MaxBet = maxBet, 
            ResetOnMaxLoss = resetOnMaxLoss, 
            StopOnMaxLoss =  stopOnMaxLoss, 
            StopMaxBalance = stopMaxBalance
};
var result = DiceWebAPI.PlaceAutomatedBets(Session, betSettingsContext);
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, but don't you think there's a much more simply solution? because I have source and compiled and I don't think there's a such big difference. I rather suppose that coder change a line or two or sth and forgot to update src release - not changing whole way of programming. but of course - i'll try (but i don't think it would work because there are many calls in this app to this parametres) thx again and if you have better idea - write

Comment: Does the source have a method with 12 parameters?

Comment: this is the source. i've paste it. none of my source for now. and it's using this through all app

Comment: If that's the signature, you must obey it. Yes, you have to build a context but then that's where C# is type safe.

Comment: Like my example, create a `AutomatedBetsSettings` object, fill the items and then pass it in. If you are doing this in lots of places, then you can create a factory method. Do you know what I mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this.

```
var result = DiceWebAPI.PlaceAutomatedBets(
            HttpContext.Current.Session, baseBet, guessLow, guessHigh,
            betCount > Session["MaxBetBatchSize"] ? Session["MaxBetBatchSize"] : betCount,
            resetOnWin, resetOnLoss,
            increaseOnWin, increaseOnLoss,
            maxBet, resetOnMaxLoss, stopOnMaxLoss, stopMaxBalance);
```

Comment: absolutely not working (HttpContext name dosen't exist and so on)

Comment: change line HttpContext to System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session

Comment: none. wrong namespace. i've checked - in this it doesn't exist